# Google App Maker - Problems setting UI visibility by role

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I am trying to set a widget's visibility based on **one of many roles**. The log seems to return the proper values, but the ui doesn't respond properly.

**Logger is showing:**
User Role: Admins
Server returns: true

**Client Script:** ('visible' property)

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(visible) {
  console.log("Server returns: " + visible);
}).vis_canUnwind(@user.roles)
```

**Server Script:**

```
function vis_canUnwind(role){
console.log("User Role: " + role);
  if(role == "Admins"||"DeptHeads"){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
   }
}
```

If I use **(@user.roles).indexOf('Admins') > -1** *(as the visible property)* then it works properly so I'm sure it's related to my code.

Comment: I would suggest using the visibility property for this. They actually changed the settings in app maker to make an even simpler binding. I would use '@user.role.Admins || '@user.role.DeptHeads. Scripts generally don't seem to work very well when they are used in bindings.

Comment: Thank you! That was nowhere to be found in Google's "Secure the UI" documentation.

Comment: Do keep in mind that widget visibility settings are not considered to be secure. You will want to set your model security settings whether data will be loaded based on roles or what not. At the UI level the only thing that is considered to be secure is if you set your page security settings because that will be checked against the server. But any widget visibility binding is a client side setting and therefore could be surpassed by someone that knows what they are doing.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very low risk web app so no worries there.